# psql authentication fails with --host=localhost

Tags: postgresql, psql

With the command:

```
psql --dbname=mattermost --username=mmuser --password
```

then if I place the password it succeeds, but if I write:

```
psql --host=localhost --dbname=mattermost --username=mmuser --password
```

then the same password gives authentication fails

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

So in this one try using

```
 psql --host=127.0.0.1 --dbname=mattermost --username=mmuser --password
```

check the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for further info. So if below line in your pg_hba.conf file

```
 host    all         all        localhost             trust
```

then it will start working with localhost also